# Microsoft Graph API: Is there any limit on payload size of a POST request

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

Is there any limit on the payload size of a POST request in Graph API. This [link](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample/issues/18) suggests a limitation of 4MB. Is there any reference to this in the documentation?

Also is there any limitation for the outlook REST API

Comment: Is there is a specific scenario where you're running into limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is correct, individual requests to Microsoft Graph must be 4MB of less. An example from the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/message_post_attachments) for `/attachments`:

> Since there is currently a limit of 4MB on the total size of each REST request, this limits the size of the attachment you can add to under 4MB.

Comment: Thanks Marc. In my application I am trying to use 'POST /users/{id|userPrincipalName}/messages' API and inject message directly into users inbox. The messages might have attachments.

Comment: Just to be clear, this would create a `draft` message. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I read the docs again and realised 'POST /messages' can create only draft messages. I want to inject an actual message not 'draft' messages. Looks like there is no api to do so and I have to send via SMTP only. Is this right or can it be done via API?

Comment: That is correct. A number of properties and events rely on the SMTP pipeline. For example, saving a `draft` wouldn't trigger a push notification to their phone's email client like an incoming email would. What about sending a message to themselves? That would push it through the correct pipeline without requiring setting up another mailbox.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Mark. Sending a message to themselves would work for my use case.